# String manipulation using batch

Tags: windows, csv, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Below is the crud output of my batch script

```
"kxip12","triss-s16-vm","","triss-db02-vm","false","true","false","MySQL","false"," "," ","PTROWEUTIL","PTROWETP","false","172.17.6.167:7081,172.17.6.248:7081,172.17.1.93:7081,172.17.6.167:7081","64","18","18","512"," "," ","true","FOO","BAR","RAID:12345",""," ","","tp.cfg:TP.remotedInterface.active=FALSE","tp.cfg:TP.LoopBackDestination.Count=1","tp.cfg:TP.trading.orderHistoryReflected=true","tp.cfg:TP.glueInterface.acceptorService_tcp=gatedev28z3.itgssi.com:32101","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

I want only `"kxip12"` as o/p. I am looking for something similar to awk in bash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
(for /f "delims=," %%a in (file.csv) do echo(%%a)>filenew.csv
```

---

You should better use [awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%a in (%str%) do set first=%%a
set first=%first:"=%
```

Comment: @echo off
set /p serv=SenderCompID? 
echo %serv% > servers11.txt
for /F "delims=;" %%i in (servers11.txt) do  (
type \\triss-s02-vm\ITG\Triton\GroupConfig.csv | grep -i %%i >temp12.txt
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set first=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in (temp12.txt) do (
    if !first!==1 echo %%i
    set first=0
)
endlocal
pause
)